# Trying to create a scattergraph on Excel based on presence

Tags: excel, graph

I'm currently trying to create a scatter graph on excel. I have a large database of Sharks with their ID numbers (1-60) and the dates on which they were either present (1) or absent (0) from the 25/06/16 - 01/09/16.

I'd like to create the scattergraph with the dates running along the X axis and the Sharks individual ID's on the Y axis. Creating a point each time a shark was present on that date. Ideally there would only be points when the sharks were present. I am currently having issues as excel is registering the (1) values as numerical values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your table probably looks something like this, with dates across the top and shark ids going down.

```
     1/1/16 1/2/16
...  ...    ...
32   1      0
33   1      1
...  ...    ...
```

Now wouldn't it be nice if you had a table that, instead of 1s and 0s, had the shark id as values. Like this:

```
     1/1/16 1/2/16
...  ...    ...
32   32     0
33   33     33
...  ...    ...
```

This would make things so much better because you can now scatter plot the dates and the numbers below to make the chart you are looking for.

How might we go about doing this?

One simple way of doing this is to use multiplication:

```
     A    B      C
1         1/1/16    1/2/16        1/1/16      1/2/16
...  ...  ...    ...              ...         ...
32   32   1     0                 =B32*$A32   =C32*$A32
33   33   1     1                 =B32*$A33   =C32*$A33
...  ...  ...    ...
```

A fancier method, instead of `=B32*$A32` is to do:

```
=IF(B32=1, $A32, NA())
```

The reason this works out better is that in the first version, the scatter plot will draw the 0s and in the second version with the NAs, it won't clutter your plot.